# Converting java object to xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

How can i convert java object to xml? I am trying to convert an incoming java object to xml in spring integration with a converter bean. is there another way than marshalling in Jaxb ? like using @TypeConverter. Or implementing converter class.

Comment: You can use Jackson library : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `@TypeConverter`, but looks that that is an EclipseLink feature for JPA. In the end it has this JavaDoc on the `@Convert`:

```
/**
 * Constant name for the reserved XML converter.
 * This will use JAXB to convert the object to and from XML.
 */
public static final String XML = "xml";
```

So, it still would require from you a JaxB `Marshaller` to be configured.

Not sure from here why do you ask about Spring Integration if your end goal is JPA...

Anyway: the best way to convert object to XML in Spring Integration is indeed use a `MarshallingTransformer` which could be configured with any `org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller` impl, not only JaxB.

If you are looking for some conversion way in between, you may also look into `MappingJackson2MessageConverter` when you inject an `XmlMapper` from Jackson lib.

For better assisting you, we definitely need to know more about your use-case and what and how you'd like to marshal into an XML.